# Как оформляется диалог в стихотворной форме? Ставится ли тире перед прямой речью?

Tags: прямая-речь

Как оформляется диалог в стихотворной форме? Ставится ли тире перед прямой речью? Или его можно опустить? Кавычки не ставятся, так как оформление в абзацы уже выделение само по себе...

Answer (score 1):

Прямая речь может иметь форму диалога. Диалог оформляется двумя способами:

1. реплики следуют каждая с нового абзаца, не заключаются в кавычки, перед каждой ставится тире:

> Александр Блок
>
> -Всё ли спокойно в народе?
>
> -Нет. Император убит.
>
> Кто-то о новой свободе
>
> На площадях говорит.
>
> -Все ли готовы подняться?
>
> -Нет. Каменеют и ждут.
>
> Кто-то велел дожидаться:
>
> Бродят и песни поют.

https://stihi-russkih-poetov.ru/tags/stihotvorenie-dialog

2. Реплики следуют в строку:

> «А есть у вас друзья?» — «Помилуй бог!
>
> Они меня покамест не тревожат!
>
> Ну вот, я рассказал вам все, что мог,
>
> Теперь и вы расскажете, быть может?»
>
> «Увы, исполнен горестных тревог
>
> Рассказ мои долгий! Боль мне сердце гложет!»
>
> Байрон. Дон-Жуан

А вот у Пушкина в "Евгении Онегине":

> «Так ты женат! не знал я ране!
>
> Давно ли?» — Около двух лет. —
>
> «На ком?» — На Лариной. — «Татьяне!»
>
> — Ты ей знаком? — «Я им сосед».
>
> — О, так пойдем же. — Князь подходит
>
> К своей жене и ей подводит
>
> Родню и друга своего.